# Reexporting JSS via index.js causing unwanted rerenders in unrelated components

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, fast-refresh

I have a large codebase where Material UI with [it's JSS](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#createstyles-styles-styles) are being used.

```
jss/
  a.js Default or named export `astyle` 
  b.js Default or named export `bstyle`
  index.js - Re-exports the JSS
```

All other files import like `import { astyle } from './jss'`

```
ComponentA.jsx - contains `import { astyle } from './jss'`
ComponentB.jsx - contains `import { bstyle } from './jss'`
App.jsx - imports ComponentA and ComponentB
```

Updating `a.js` causes `ComponentB` to re-render as well, is there any way I can tell webpack to not reload the entire `jss/index.js`?

[image]

Components work fine

```
componets/
  ComponentC.jsx - default or named export
  ComponentD.jsx - default or named export
  index.js - Re-exports the components

App.jsx - import { ComponentC, ComponentD } from './components'
```

Updating `ComponentC` will not re-render `ComponentD` or `components/index.js`

[image]

I'm looking for the least disruptive solution and would prefer not to import all the styles directly by file name getting rid of the `jss/index.js`

Here is the demo [repo](https://github.com/louisnow/material-ui-jss-fast-refresh-test) and is based on the example from the fast refresh [repo here](https://github.com/pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/tree/main/examples/webpack-dev-server)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out simply upgrading to webpack 5 fixes it, you can view the updated repo at this [branch](https://github.com/louisnow/material-ui-jss-fast-refresh-test/tree/webpack5)